# Fresh Anaconda install gives "ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' from 'zmq.backend.cython'"

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, ipython, spyder

updated my previous Spyder installation, causing a dependency issue, so decided to un- and reinstall Anaconda.

DLed and installed Anaconda3.2018.12.  Install completed successfully, but upon launch, kernel doesn't launch, giving the following error message in the console:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in
> _run_module_as_main "__main__", mod_spec) File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
> exec(code, run_globals) File "C:\Program
> Files\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\__main__.py",
> line 11, in  start.main() File "C:\Program
> Files\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py",
> line 289, in main from ipykernel.kernelapp import IPKernelApp File
> "C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\__init__.py",
> line 2, in  from .connect import * File "C:\Program
> Files\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 18, in 
> import jupyter_client File "C:\Program
> Files\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\__init__.py", line 4,
> in  from .connect import * File "C:\Program
> Files\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 23,
> in  import zmq File "C:\Program
> Files\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 47, in  from
> zmq import backend File "C:\Program
> Files\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in
> reraise(*exc_info) File "C:\Program
> Files\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in
> reraise raise value File "C:\Program
> Files\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in
> 
> _ns = select_backend(first) File "C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 27, in
> select_backend mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api) File
> "C:\Program
> Files\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line
> 6, in  from . import (constants, error, message, context, ImportError:
> cannot import name 'constants' from 'zmq.backend.cython' (C:\Program
> Files\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py)
```

I tried upgrading pyzmq, to no avail.  Uninstall and reinstall of pyzmq also didn't work.

I've also upgrading ipython to 7.2 on the off chance there was an unspecified dependency, no dice.

Any ideas for resolving this?

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing two Python versions, the one in here:

`C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3`

and the other one in here

`C:\Program Files\Python36\`

Since you claim you want to use Anaconda, you need to remove the second installation to get things working as expected.

Comment: Thanks, Carlos...I was actually able to get this back working again by uninstalling Anaconda3 v. 201812, and reinstalling the prior functioning version 5.2.  Is it best practice to remove the standalone python installation (3.6 in this case), when installing Anaconda for some reason?